# Emulating LEFT JOIN on MongoDB using MapReduce/Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, join, database

I have a mongo database with few collections such as a user in the system (id, name, email) and list of projects (id, name, list of users who have access)

**User**

```
{
"_id": 1,
"name": "John",
"email": "john@domain.com"
}
{
"_id": 2,
"name": "Sam",
"email": "sam@domain.com"
}
```

**Project**

```
{
"_id": 1,
"name": "My Project1",
"users": [1,2]
}
{
"_id": 2,
"name": My Project2",
"users": [2]
}
```

In my dashboard, I display a list of projects and the names of its users. To support names - I've changed the `"users"` field to now also include the name:

```
{
"_id": 2,
"name": "My Project2",
"users": [{"_id":2,"name":"Sam"}]
}
```

But on several pages, I now need to also print their email address and later on - maybe also display their image.

Since I don't want to start and embed the entire **User** document in each project, I'm looking for a way to do a **LEFT JOIN** and pick the values I need from the **User** collection.

Performances are NOT important so much on those pages and I rather prefer an easy way to manage my data. So basically I'm looking for a way to query for a list of all projects and associated users with different fields from the original **User** document.

I've read about the map-reduce and aggregation option of mongo and to be honest - I'm not sure which to use and how to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: why not just embed the user info in the project collection? joins are not possible in mongo (by design) and by embedding you'll get results faster and easier.

Comment: @pennstatephil , as I explained in my question, I need to extract different fields from the user collection on different pages of my site. In addition, a user might change his details (his name, email etc) and I was looking for a way to avoid updating all collections where a user is embedded.

Comment: if you need relational db style logic, I would recommend using a relational db :) not every tool is right for the job.

Comment: For all other cases, the nosql model fits very well to my requirements and actually works much better than traditional relational database. Only in few specific cases I need to aggregate data from multiple collections and am trying to figure out the mongo way for doing so.

Comment: well, then I would recommend using @andrei's answer and try to implement it in code. make some sort of GetUserInfo(id/id-list) function and accept the performance hit of having to query a 2nd collection.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDb doesn't support joins in any form even by using MapReduce and Aggregation Framework. Only way you could implement join between collection is in your code. So just implement LEFT JOIN logic in your code.